# WebApp for Audio

Tags: javascript, php, python, jquery, html

I would like to build a webapp for audio „confoguration“. The basics are clear for me but there‘s one point I don‘t know how to accomplish it:

There will be several aufio files uploaded and included in the user dashboard. The user can see the files listed in their dashboard and should be now able to grab and drop them in a new space at the end of the site. After that they can export the whole new file. So out of 5 single audio files will be generated 1 whole file.

sorry.. do you get what I mean?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: can you explain what „confoguration“ means?

Comment: @madalinivascu maybe same as `aufio`

Comment: sorry that was typo on my phone.. I mean „configuration“ and „audio“

Comment: @Lithilion not yet no. I‘m a bit newer and didn‘t get the startong point for this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like jQuery sortables in order to create the lists in your dashboard. Take a look here https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists .

In case you don't want to use jQuery in your project, a search for "js sortable lists" should provide you with plenty other solutions.

In case I understood your question wrong and you are asking how to concatenate audio files, you may want to check out m4tthumphrey's ConcatAudioFilter https://gist.github.com/m4tthumphrey/a863aa64dd541cfb4472 to get an idea how this may be achieved.

(I assume you are using php serverside, as the post is tagged with php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about combining 5 audio files in one file. You can use ffmpeg. You can check the link, this is the node module for ffmpeg: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg.